# Android Play Console - how to close or remove an "Open testing track"

Tags: android, google-play

Currently I have an app with an Open testing track(build number 33) that i don't know how to remove. And as a side effect I have a closed Alpha track(build number 42) unavailable to testers because they only can see the Open testing track.

**How can I remove or make invisible to testers the Open testing track?**

[image]

Comment: have you found any solutions to this? we have the same problem and cannot remove or deactivate an older app bundle

Answer (score 3):

You can `Pause track` of the open testing by pressing `Pause track` button:

[image: screenshot1]

Then press `Pause test`

[image: screenshot2]

**BUT** I think your problem with closed testing is that you did not add the tester properly, please make sure you added them correctly.

Comment: The testers list in the closed track is fine, the problem is that even when the open testing track is inactive as you can see in my screenshots the release under the open testing track remains active(Available to limited testers)... and I don't know how to deactivate the release under the open testing track :/

Answer (score -8):

i think.. you could have another account in a bank, this account have active and you have putt this card in google play and after remove the first account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).